# Google+ share snippet not populating data from a blog

Tags: php, seo, wordpress-theming, google-plus

We just made a re-design of the company I work with of the [company wordpress blog](http://blog.voicebunny.com/2013/02/21/how-voicebunny-gets-professional-voice-overs-so-fast/) to make it more SEO friendly, improving all we could. However I still have an issue with the [Google+ share button](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/) you can see we have 2 sets of social buttons 3 in the header (facebook, google+ and twitter) these are to share the site and 3 buttons at the end of the post next to "*Did you enjoy this article? Share it!*" to share the article.

When clicking the "**G+ share**" button the snippet plug-in is not using the metadata of the site like the title and description:

[image]

And in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/snippet/) it says that's all I need, because I'm using the **Open Graph protocol**, but when I test it this is the result, which is not using the information set in the metadata:

https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://blog.voicebunny.com/2013/02/21/how-voicebunny-gets-professional-voice-overs-so-fast/

And the last thing I'm totally lost is when testing with the rich-snippets tool everything looks fine:

[http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=http%3A%2F%2Fblog.voicebunny.com%2F2013%2F02%2F21%2Fhow-voicebunny-gets-professional-voice-overs-so-fast%2F&html=](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets?url=http://blog.voicebunny.com/2013/02/21/how-voicebunny-gets-professional-voice-overs-so-fast/&html=)

Any idea how to fix the snippet? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What are the parameters you're using for the Share button. It seems odd to me that the text from the description of the share aren't found anywhere on the page itself.

Comment: I'm also wondering if there is a cache issue. The Googlebot used has been known to cache snippet information for an unknown length of time.

Comment: `<div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-annotation="none"></div>`
This is in the body tag, and I'm not sure I did the change a couple weeks ago.

Comment: I'm not sure, to be honest. The canonical link looks correct. There are extra and redundant metadata tags, but I don't know why that would be messing it up and causing it to use text that isn't even on that page. You might want to put a data-href tag in the <div>, if you can... but I don't know that would really help, I'm grasping at straws.

Comment: That was solution, I'm now using the permalink to the post and add it to the button in the href="", and after a couple hours it worked :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clearly document an apparent solution:

Putting a data-href tag as part of the  that explicitly points to the page would make it clear where the metadata should be pulled from. Although there are other ways it can get this data (the cannonical link, for example), making it explicit as part of the button is best.

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure, but I think you also have to update (or remove?) the `itemprop` meta at the beginning of your template:

```
<meta itemprop="name" content="The Carrot Chronicle">
<meta itemprop="description" content="The Official Blog of Mr. VoiceBunny">
```

Comment: I've noticed social widgets tend to cache themselves at server level. Did you try with a fresh page?